# Indentify stock prices trading under the 1 year estimate

Tags: stockquotes, interactive-brokers, tws

At every quarter analysts give their price estimation for a given stock. Available for example on Yahoo finance as 1 year estimate.

I want to find a way (build a scanner?) that allows me to have a dashboard of stocks that will announce their quarterly earning results in the next month. Including columns identifying their current stock price , their 1 year price estimate, their market cap And their earnings date.

I use interactive brokerS (IB) is it possible to do it under IB? if not please siggest another platform and how to do it on.

Answer (score 0):

With the **IB API** you can solve nearly everything but it's very complex and not very well documented.

In your question I read your need of

- close price
- 1 year estimation
- market cap
- earnings date

For the first you do a `reqMktData` and receive last close or realtime price (different fields in the message data type). For the market cap you calculate with the shares amount by `reqFundamentalData` using `recordType="ReportSnapshot"` (The part is called `CoGeneralInfo` and for `AAPL` I found the line `<SharesOut Date="2017-12-30" TotalFloat="5077957038.0"> 5081651000.0</SharesOut>` a few weeks ago).

I think you'll find estimations and earnings dates in all the possible `xml`-files, too.

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: You right it is si badly documented that i dont know where to start with IB API. Do you have a link for a tutorial? I am a data scientist meaning i can pull data from the API to work on a local Anaconda/python environment or online using Kaggle kernels. Also please if you know of another API dont hesitate to share or if you have your own code for pulling data from IB API with a list for the dofferent keys do not hesitate to share. I used to use Yahoo finance but they closed the service.

Comment: Just start to write a code for requesting and receiving the close price. You have to open the connection, request with `reqMktData` and receive within a handler and catch the `message.field` number 9.
Try out the `ibpy`-library for python.

Comment: Okay will do thank you very much! On another note I am curious as you are the first quant trader I talked to. Do you have a blog or anything online where you share your lesson learned or algos / strategies on the market?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know if it's possible but if it helps mark my answer as a helpful one because I'm new here, too. :)

Comment: Just did. Told me something about 15 points reputation but my vote was recorded to help you move up the reputation ladder although it doesnt show publicly. But definitely you have been helpful!

Comment: Thank you. Good luck. To work with these data sets is fun, too!

Comment: Thanks! Any algos/strategies, lessons learned as a quant trader on the markets or online blogs you have/follow you think might be great for a beginner like me you can share? I trade mostly options